# apply_filters to $GLOBALS

Tags: filters, shortcode, globals

I'm building a onepage website, using the Pootle Page Building plugin. With get_page, I show every separate page on 1 page. To target the Pootle Page Builder content, I'm using the following code:

```
$content = $GLOBALS['Pootle_Page_Builder_Render_Layout']->panels_render( $page_data->ID );
```

When I try to implement a plugin like a carousel, where I need to use a shortcode, the shortcode doens't work.

For the shortcode to work, I need to use

```
apply_filters('the_content', $page_data->post_content);
```

Except, instead of `'the_content'`
I use:

```
$content = $GLOBALS['Pootle_Page_Builder_Render_Layout']->panels_render( $page_data->ID );
```

Does anyone perhaps know how I can add apply_filters to `$GLOBALS['whatever']` so the shortcodes will work

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `$GLOBALS['Pootle_Page_Builder_Render_Layout']` carries an instance of `Pootle_Page_Builder_Render_Layout`, the method `panels_render()` [returns a string](https://github.com/pootlepress/pootle-page-builder/blob/5a242ce303480297bb926fef16fe92fa88787d64/inc/class-render-layout.php#L111).

So you can simply pass the method call as an argument to `apply_filters()`:

```
$content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $GLOBALS['Pootle_Page_Builder_Render_Layout']->panels_render( $page_data->ID ) );
```

I'm not sure whether this is an intended use of the API of the plugin, as `Pootle_Page_Builder_Render_Layout::panels_render()` remove some default filters from the content (`wptexturize`, `wpautop` and `convert_chars`). So maybe your concern is also worth a question on the plugin [support forum](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/pootle-page-builder).

Comment: Thanks for your response David!

I tried it, but sadly the shortcodes still don't work.

I also tried to activate the plugins manually in the page.php, like this:

echo "<div class='content'>";
echo "<h2>$title</h2>";
echo $content;
if (is_page( 83 ))  {
echo do_shortcode('[wds id="1"]');
} 
if ( is_page( 109 ) ) {
echo do_shortcode('[formidable id="2"]');
}
echo "</div>";

This time, the plugins DO show, but sadly they show on every single page on the onepage website, although I only target the pages 83 and 109.

Maybe this is an easier fix?

Many Thanks.

Comment: Your question was, how to use `apply_filters()` on the returning value of the page builder object. Please don't write code in comment but update your question.